# What does "Network Unroutable" means?

Tags: network, nodes, peers

I just started running bitcoin core on a dedicated laptop.  I wanted to see if my node is connected to my Wasabi wallet so I sent some sats from Strike. In the peers list Wasabi shows up but under Network it shows Unroutable. Is that normal?  What does that mean? Is my node connected? Am I sovereign?

I looked in my Wasabi logs and it showed that the block was acquired from a local p2p connection. I'm guessing that my node is connected.  I just wonder about the Network being Unroutable.  I appreciate the feedback.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/21747

Comment: Yes, this helps. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From the [Wasabi docs](https://docs.wasabiwallet.io/using-wasabi/BitcoinFullNode.html#using-an-already-existing-remote-bitcoin-full-node):

> There are two ways to confirm that your Wasabi client is connected to
> your own full node.
>
> First, in the Wasabi logs. Once you receive a transaction Wasabi
> downloads the block containing that transaction from your node, and in
> the logs you should see: `Block acquired from local P2P connection`.
>
> Second, by checking the connected peers inside your full node. Wasabi
> will show up as one of the connected peers while it is downloading a
> block. You can check this in the Bitcoin Core / Knots GUI by clicking
> on `Window -> Peers`. During the period when Wasabi is fetching a
> block, it will show up in the `User Agent` column. Alternatively, you
> can use the Bitcoin RPC call `bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo` and see the
> Wasabi client listed.
>
> https://docs.wasabiwallet.io/using-wasabi/BitcoinFullNode.html#using-an-already-existing-remote-bitcoin-full-node

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing but it means "Local network".